# ckeditor issue in dynamic form with jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am making dynamic form with jquery. It produces as many textareas as the value of the input named number. But since the textareas are ckeditor, normally ckeditor should appear. but unfortunately only the standard textarea appears instead. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">PCS</label>
<input type="number" name="slider2_number" id="slider2_number" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="sonuclar"></div>
$("#slider2_number").change(function(){
            let number = $(this).val();
            $(".sonuclar .form-group").remove();
            for(let i = 1; i<=number; i++){
                $(".sonuclar").append('<div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">'+i+ '. pcs title</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="slider2_title_'+i+'"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">'+i+' .Description</label><br><textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="slider2_icerik_'+i+'"></textarea></div>').show('slow');
            }
        });
```

Comment: does the ckeditor come with a css file? If so wouldn't you need to do something like ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ckeditor.css">``` at the top of your html file

Comment: See this example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xcchcaptain/reoh7j74/

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Default configuration of ckeditor
        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
            config.language = 'es';
            config.uiColor = '#F7B42C';
            config.height = 300;
            config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
        
        };
        $("#slider2_number").change(function(){
        let number = $(this).val();
                    $(".sonuclar .form-group").remove();
                    for(let i = 1; i<=number; i++){
                        $(".sonuclar").append('<div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">'+i+ '. pcs title</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="slider2_title_'+i+'"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">'+i+' .Description</label><br>'+
'<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor'+i+'" name="slider2_icerik_'+i+'"></textarea></div>').show('slow');//create dynamic id by adding index
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor'+i);//invoke ckeditor using dynamic id
                    }
                });
```